# How to achieve this animation with multiple CAShapeLayer

Tags: swift, core-animation, cashapelayer, cabasicanimation, cakeyframeanimation

I'm having a lot of trouble exporting a video with animated layers.

The final goal is to export to a video (that's why I need this done with `CALayer`s) a moving `CAShapeLayer` around the screen and a line following its trace.

First of all, I have an array of `CGPoint` with all the coordinate points which a `CAShapeLayer` should use to animate itself. To create the animation I'm using a `CAKeyframeAnimation`.

```
let values = [CGPoint(x: 50, y: 100), 
              CGPoint(x: 100, y: 150)] //Example values

let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation()
animation.keyPath = "position"
animation.values = values
animation.duration = videoLength
```

With this, I'm able to show the `CALayer` moving around the screen. It's 1 value per frame of the video, it's a 1:1 value.

The real problem comes with adding a line that shows the path of the `CAShapeLayer`.

What I think I might do, is to create lines with `UIBezierPath`, animate them and add each line

```
lines.forEach { (line) in
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    for (index, point) in line.points.enumerated() {
        if index == 0 {
            path.move(to: point)
        } else {
            path.addLine(to: point)
        }
    }
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = line.color.cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 4
    shapeLayer.position = animatedLayer.position
    shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
    shapeLayer.opacity = 0

    shapeLayers.append(shapeLayer)
}
```

And to animate the lines...

```
var timeOffset: Double = 0
let eachLineTime = totalTime / Double(shapeLayers.count)
for shapeLayer in shapeLayers {
    
    CATransaction.begin()
    
    mainLayer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    
    let strokeAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
    strokeAnimation.fromValue = 0
    strokeAnimation.toValue = 1
    strokeAnimation.duration = eachLineTime
    strokeAnimation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + timeOffset
    
    let opacityAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
    opacityAnimation.fromValue = 0
    opacityAnimation.toValue = 1
    opacityAnimation.duration = eachLineTime
    opacityAnimation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + timeOffset
    
    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor
        shapeLayer.opacity = 1
    }
    
    shapeLayer.add(strokeAnimation, forKey: nil)
    shapeLayer.add(opacityAnimation, forKey: nil)
    timeOffset += eachLineTime
    CATransaction.commit()
}
```

I need them to be different lines because I want to change the color of each line when it finishes each animation.

I'm getting the next output in Swift Playgrounds

[image]

But I'm not getting anything when I export the video in the app.

How can I simply add a trail of the first `CAShapeLayer` to see the (square in this case) moving path?

How can I move the `CABasicAnimation` with the same timing of the `CAKeyframeAnimation`?